# How to build an api endpoint in Node.js that upload file to s3 with returning the progress to front-end through HTTP?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I want to build a backend server api that expose an endpoint POST `/api/v0/<entity>/upload`.

This endpoint receive a large file (from hundreds MB to 2G ) and some meta data through HTTP request body. It upload the file to AWS S3 and return the progress back to front-end through HTTP response, so that front-end can use the progress and show it onto UI.

The reason why I want to put upload progress behind server is because I don't want to expose AWS ACCESS KEY on browser.

The concept is like using server as an S3 upload proxy, but with additional tasks such as create a database record that reference the uploaded file's url.

Anyone known how to build this? Or is there any better solution or thoughts on this? Thanks!

Comment: The clients are uploading directly to S3, right?  So, the server isn't going to know the upload progress.  In any case, show what API you're using to do the upload... there are lots of ways to do it, and the answer to your question is dependent on that information.

Comment: @Brad sorry for the misleading. I've edit the question. In short, I want to build a server api endpoint that proxies the s3 upload, return progress in response and create db record after upload. Is this a suggested practice?

Comment: No, ideally the client just uploads to S3 directly.  You can sign a PUT URL and upload directly from the client.

Comment: I see. But this means we have to expose access_key in browser, any security concern on this?

Comment: No, you expose your AccessKeyID, but not the secret.  There are zero security concerns with the key ID being revealed, provided that you don't reveal the secret.  The idea is that you pre-sign a URL which can be cryptographically verified by Amazon's servers.  It's sort of a stamp on the message that only you can make and AWS knows how to verify that you were the one that made it, since they assigned the key and secret in the first place.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit confused. Do you know any reference that talks about the solution you mentioned? I use `aws-sdk` in JS to do the upload request. I need to provide both the `access_key_id` and `access_secret_key` to initiate the `aws-sdk`. Anyways that I can only provide KeyID in browser?

Comment: Actually, server-side, in your Node.js code, you'll sign the URL.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property  Then, you'll send that URL to your client by whatever means you want.  From there, it's a simple `fetch(url, {body: file})`.

Comment: Oh! This might work! This means I won't use `aws-sdk` on browser right?

Comment: That's correct.  No need for a library for basic S3 operations... they're all just HTTP.  (Some people do use the SDK client-side as it has other utility functions, but it's definitely not needed for this.)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks you so much for the detailed explanation and your patience! I'll give it a try.

Comment: Aside from this, for people who use `aws-sdk` on client, since they do need to provide secret_key to initiate it, what is the recommended way to ensure security in this kind of scenario?

Comment: Depends on what they're doing with it, but yes if they're making S3 operations, they'll need to provide the secret to the client.  In that case, there's no way to hide it.  If someone has the secret, they can do anything that the access key is allowed to do, full stop.  An example of where this is desirable... I was working on a project that would allow you to stream video into your own S3 buckets.  So, video was recorded in-browser and chunked into files that someone would send to their owned S3 bucket.  The user provided the key/secret.  I used the SDK client-side for that project.

Comment: I see, then I think the best way is to carefully restricted the access of that key before expose it.
Thanks for the kindness sharing. I've learned tremendous amount of knowledge!